# Android Visibility and Layout GONE VISIBLE Cycle Overlaps the Layout

Tags: android, visibility, android-relativelayout, cycle, visible

If you don't mind looking at the video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWFsmeBJ4l0

I have a Layout with the parent: Relative Layout, 3 Linear Layout as the Children: Title, Menu, and Content. The Menu is manipulated to be GONE onCreate, then Visible after the certain event, and GONE again after the opposite of the event. The problem is after the first cycle of GONE VISIBLE GONE, doing GONE again will ruin the UI, the Content then overlaps with the Menu. Can anyone tell me what happened?

This is the code for the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/metro_dark_blue"
    android:clipChildren="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/titleBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/collaborationButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/collaboration_button_xml"
            android:clickable="true" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/titleBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/presento"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/connectButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/titleBar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/connect_button_xml"
        android:clickable="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/titleDropShadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleBar"
        android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menuBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleDropShadow"
        android:background="@drawable/header_gradient"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/remote_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_button_xml"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_remote"
                android:layout_width="85.5dp"
                android:layout_height="58.5dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/remote_control_button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/file_manager_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_button_xml"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_file_manager"
                android:layout_width="85.5dp"
                android:layout_height="58.5dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/file_manager_button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/desktop_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_button_xml"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_desktop"
                android:layout_width="85.5dp"
                android:layout_height="58.5dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/desktop_mode_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/menuBar"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible" >

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Code that handle Visibility

```
public void connectService(String ip, String hostType, String name) {
    server = new ConnectedServer(ip, hostType, "Presento");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have been connected to Presento Server with IP: " + ip, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) fragmentContainer.getLayoutParams();
    //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) belowMenu.getLayoutParams();
    //param2.height = 65;
    //param2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.fragment_container);
    //param2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.titleBar);
    belowMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        belowMenu.startAnimation(new MyScaler(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 500, belowMenu, false));

    //belowMenu.setLayoutParams(param2);
    //params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.menuBar);
    //fragmentContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
    //fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //fragmentContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

And this is the code that handle when it is GONE

```
connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //if not yet connected to a server, find a server through jmdns and get the ip
                if (server == null) {
                    //setting device's ip address
                    myIpAddress = getMyIpAddress();
                    InetAddress inet = intToInetAddress(ipStringToInt(myIpAddress));
                    if (myIpAddress.equals("")) alertMessage("You don't seem to be connected to a Wi-Fi Service, please make sure that you are connected and try to connect again.", "Something went wrong");
                    else {
                        new SeekServer(inet, MenuActivity.this).execute(jmdns);
                    }
                }
                //server already connected
                else {
                    FragmentManager FM = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction FT = FM.beginTransaction();
                    String sessionID = pref.getString("sessionID", "0");
                    FT.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                    try {
                    RemoteControlFragment remote = (RemoteControlFragment)FM.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                    if (sessionID.equals("0")) {
                        join = new JoinSessionFragment();
                        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, join);
                        FT.commit();
                    } else {
                        String accountName = pref.getString("accountName", "");
                        status.setText(accountName);
                        FT.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                        TutorialFragment tutor = new TutorialFragment();
                        FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, tutor);
                        FT.addToBackStack(null);
                        FT.commit();
                    }
                    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
                        try {
                        FileManagerFragment manager = (FileManagerFragment)FM.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                        if (sessionID.equals("0")) {
                            join = new JoinSessionFragment();
                            FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, join);
                            FT.commit();
                        } else {
                            String accountName = pref.getString("accountName", "");
                            status.setText(accountName);
                            FT.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                            TutorialFragment tutor = new TutorialFragment();
                            FT.replace(R.id.fragment_container, tutor);
                            FT.addToBackStack(null);
                            FT.commit();
                        }
                        }
                        catch (ClassCastException ex2) {

                        }
                    }


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have been disconnected from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    belowMenu.startAnimation(new MyScaler(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 500, belowMenu, true));

                    server = null;
                        if (jmdns != null) {
                        jmdns.unregisterAllServices();
                        try {
                            jmdns.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
```

The animation class

```
public class MyScaler extends ScaleAnimation {

        private View mView;

        private LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

        private int mMarginBottomFromY, mMarginBottomToY;

        private boolean mVanishAfter = false;

        public MyScaler(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int duration, View view,
                boolean vanishAfter) {
            super(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
            setDuration(duration);
            mView = view;
            mVanishAfter = vanishAfter;
            mLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int height = mView.getHeight();
            mMarginBottomFromY = (int) (height * fromY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin - height;
            mMarginBottomToY = (int) (0 - ((height * toY) + mLayoutParams.bottomMargin)) - height;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
            if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
                int newMarginBottom = mMarginBottomFromY
                        + (int) ((mMarginBottomToY - mMarginBottomFromY) * interpolatedTime);
                mLayoutParams.setMargins(mLayoutParams.leftMargin, mLayoutParams.topMargin,
                    mLayoutParams.rightMargin, newMarginBottom);
                mView.getParent().requestLayout();
            } else if (mVanishAfter) {
                mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

    }
```

I first suspected that the animation caused that, but then i plainly use GONE and VISIBLE without the animation that resulted in the same conclusion as in the Video.

Comment: is it by using runOnUIThread() ? I tried it and the problem persists

Comment: Try to programmatically change the rules of the content Relativelayout` along with changing the visibility of the desired views.

Comment: did that as well, it doesn't work